# How to merge two lists by index

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists:

```
i = ['a', 'b', 'c']
x = [1,2,3]
```

i need to produce such dictionary:

```
xxx = { 'a': [a, 1],
'b': [b, 2],
'c': [c, 3]}
```

I have done this:

```
for indx in i:
    for indx2 in x:
        xxx.update({indx: [indx, indx2]})
```

but obvioulsy it doesnt work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using dict comprehension:

```
>>> i = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> {key: [key, value] for key, value in zip(i, x)}
{'a': ['a', 1], 'c': ['c', 3], 'b': ['b', 2]}
```

Answer (score 3):

how about this, if tuple can be the value of your dict.

```
i= ['a', 'b', 'c']

x= [1, 2, 3]

dict(zip(i,zip(i,x)))
 {'a': ('a', 1), 'b': ('b', 2), 'c': ('c', 3)}
```

Comment: Since the OP wants a lists as map values instead tupes I would change your code to `dict(zip(i,map(list,zip(i,x))))` but despite that, I really like you solution! +1